# Oracle Apex facets values

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Application Express 19.2.0.00.18 with Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release. I create a page with facets search and it works correctly. My need is to retrive the actual value of facet items but with the usual syntax (e.g. :PX_FACET_A :PX_FACET_B ...) the resulting value is not *up to date*, instead, if I open the Session dialog the items value reflects the current selection.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know, but what if you use v('PX_FACET_A') to get the value?

Comment: Same result, it seems I have to convert the facets page into a report with filters.

Comment: What is the difference between "actual value" and "current selection"?

Comment: @Dan McGhan : when loaded PX_FACET_A has a value of XY. If I change it to ZK the value returned with the syntax :PX_FACET_A (I called it actual) is still XY. In the session page the value reported is ZK (I called it current selection)

Comment: Where are you using "the syntax :PX_FACET_A (I called it actual)". That's called bind variable syntax, which needs to be handled on the server. Technically, it should be the same value as what's shown in the popup to view session state, but perhaps you're using the bind variable syntax in a place I'm not thinking of.

Comment: I just ran a test and I found that the value of the facets was transferred to persisted session state when the report was refreshed. Were you trying to access the value prior to the report updating/refreshing? You'd likely have enabled Batch Facet Changes for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a specific DA events [image]

it is possible to retrive the item value reflecting the correct selection.